# can't get the find products from the state named products

Tags: reactjs

[image: browser screenshot]

[image: code screenshot]

I have tried to do a map in same place, It works. but whenever I try to do find or filter it doesn't return anything...I have tried everything to find the bug, but couldn't find it.

Comment: What does a product object look like

Comment: Please post code here as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the id in your for loop is the index of the object, you have to compare the product.id with the addedProducts passing the index, try this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const addedProducts = getStoredCart()
    if (products.length) {
      for (const id in addedProducts) {
        const foundProduct = products.find(product => product.id === addedProducts[id])
        console.log('found Product', foundProduct)
      }
    }
  }, [products])
```

Other thing, whenever you make a question, give as much information as possible, and don't take print of the code, put it directly in the post with the code sample tool, this way you make the things easier for the one that is helping you. Hope my answer was useful for you!